# Magento 2.3 - Transform add to compare link in list to checkbox

Tags: magento2.3, compare

By default the Magneto 2.3x add to compare is a link, but we want to change this into a checkbox, so it become easier to check multiple products on the catalog product overview (list page).

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3 steps of various difficulties:

1. change the input that is in the product listing from an anchor to become a checkbox. Leaving the appearance as it is will be good though.
2. when the checkbox is hit for either of the products in the category listing, this would update the compare sidebar widget in real time (at the moment, the page is reloaded and this is not very user friendly; instead using ui components widget can enable a real time experience that does not reload the page)
3. you'd be almost there. As soon as one new product is added to the sidebar, we would have the state of the compare list changed. I suggest to add a button in the compare sidebar to save the compare list. This would just replicate what the current add to compare link does but it would do it in bulk.